# Calling a function within the same file in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export

I'm building a React App.

I have a file (user.utils.js) which contain some utils functions that I use in my reducer.

```
export const addUser = (state) => {}

export const resetUser = (state) => {}

export const countUsers = () => {}
```

My question is how can I use countUsers within resetUser?

Comment: Use functions instead, and the order doesn't matter: `export function addUser(state) {}`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
// Declar countUsers first
export const countUsers = () => {}

export const resetUser = (state) => {
  countUsers()
}
```

You can use a function from the same file (and its a good practice to declare it before you use it)